# Is the Pi melody real or fake?

Tags: pi, music-theory

Having seen [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMq9he-5HUU) video I can't stop wondering whether it is real (which is amazing) or fake. A mathematician-musician polymath opinion needed :-)

Comment: Sounds more like arpeggios and octaves?

Comment: It's real, but really if you pick a scale tonal enough (as the harmonic minor certainly is)  any "random" tones can sound nice, especially if you are allowed to vary tempo, dynamics and harmony as you feel appropriate.

Comment: True, there are more inventive ways to reference circles in a musical composition than just to map the decimal expansion to a diatonic scale. One answer below interprets it as notes in the chromatic scale, and that's a bit better. Nivertheless I always can't help but feel that people read too much in decimal expansions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's "real", but somewhat deceptive. The melodic line (the notes that he's playing one-at-a-time with his right hand) does indeed map to the decimal digits of $\pi$. However, the harmony (the notes that he's playing with his left hand), are just arpeggios in A minor and have nothing to do with $\pi$. If you removed the harmony and just listened to the melody, then you probably wouldn't find it to be particularly aesthetically pleasing, and probably no more or less so than a completely random melody composed from the same ten notes.

Comment: I don't know nothing on _aesthetic_ but you are right in it isn't pleasant. At least it is not a **completely random melody**.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [alternative take](http://www.good.is/posts/math-becomes-music-what-pi-sounds-like) on mapping $\pi$ to the diatonic scale. There are probably as many ways to translate $\pi$ to melodies as there are digits in it. And all mappings from digits to notes are arbitrary, as is the base 10 representation of numbers. It might be interesting to use a base 12 representation and map to the chromatic scale.

There have been attempts at using $\pi$ in the construction of tuning systems. The so-called Lucy tuning has a fifth of $600 + 300/\pi \approx 695.5$ cents (in tempered tuning it is 700 cents). A search for this tuning system may soon take you into New Age land, so be warned.

Answer (score 1):

This is what can be made from the digits of pi base 12 played in the 12 tones.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Dwvn73tz8E